# Materialize Autocomplete Not Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm using materialize css and js, I also have jQuery.

When I type in the textbox (input `type="text"`) every things work fine, BUT if I type something and then click on the something else (the autocomplete would be close) but its not. It's stay like this until I delete the text.

[image]

My code:

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="header-search-input" placeholder="Search" style="width: 320px !important;" autocomplete="off" />
```

and the js code:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Apple": 'https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Android_L/PNG/512/Operating_Systems/mac_os-512.png',
                "Microsoft": 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/microsoft-new-logo-simple-0.png',
                "Google": 'https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//google_logo1600.png'
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function (val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the autocomplete class to input and remove this "autocomplete =" off ".

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="autocomplete">
```

Try your js:

```
 $('input#search').autocomplete({......................});
```

Also note the order of the libraries js, first jquery.min.js, then materialize.min.js. All must go before the closure of the body tag.